# cakephp 3 pass json in checkbox

Tags: php, json, cakephp

I am working on `cakephp v3`. I am facing a problem.
I want to display loop of checkbox but the data I am getting is in json.

**Controller**

```
 public function add() {
        $building = $this->Buildings->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $building = $this->Buildings->patchEntity($building, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Buildings->save($building)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The building has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The building could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $countries = $this->Buildings->Countries->find('list');
        $this->loadModel("Amenities");
        $amenities = $this->Amenities->find('All');
        $this->set(compact('building', 'countries','amenities'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['building','amenities']);
    }
```

**View**

```
  foreach ($amenities as $key => $value) {
                   echo $this->Form->control($value, ['type' => 'checkbox']);
                }
```

And the output is

[image]

I want output in following manner.

```
Amenities

[checkbox] [checkboxname] [fa-icon] 

[checkbox] [checkboxname] [fa-icon]

[checkbox] [checkboxname] [fa-icon]
// so on
```

How I can achieve this.

I was able to set options by the following code

```
 echo $this->Form->input('country_id', ['options' => $countries, 'empty' => 'Select country']);
```

Comment: use `$data = json_decode($your_json_string, TRUE);` It will return array, then you can iterate the array according to your need.

Comment: Yes, I can use `json_decode` but I am looking for any default `cakephp` way as I used for `selectbox`.

Comment: Kindly update your question accordingly. Clearly, specify what you have tried and what you are looking for.

Comment: I already mention that I was tried with the following code
 `foreach ($amenities as $key => $value) {
                   echo $this->Form->control($value, ['type' => 'checkbox']);
                }`

Comment: I didn't see any line specifying that you want to do it in cakephp way.

Comment: I mention that in comment too

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to `control` is the field name. You're passing in an entity, which it is converting to a string in the best way it knows how. You presumably meant to use `$value->name`?